# Add new key-value pair to JSON created using object-node constructor permannently

Tags: marklogic

```
let $outputJson :=
  object-node {
    "status": "success",
    "categories": "cat"
  }
return xdmp:to-json(map:with(xdmp:from-json($outputJson), "str", "xyz"))
```

This would not be save permanently in database. So, what can I do to save this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save that JSON in the database, use the [`xdmp:document-insert()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-insert) function.

```
let $outputJson :=
  object-node {
    "status": "success",
    "categories": "cat"
  }
return 
  xdmp:document-insert("/test.json", 
    xdmp:to-json(map:with(xdmp:from-json($outputJson), "str", "xyz")) )
```

The `xdmp:document-insert()` will save to the database, but doesn't return anything. So, if you want to save it to the database and return that JSON in the result, do something like this:

```
let $outputJson :=
  object-node {
    "status": "success",
    "categories": "cat"
  }
let $outputJsonWithStr := xdmp:to-json(map:with(xdmp:from-json($outputJson), "str", "xyz"))
return 
  (xdmp:document-insert("/test.json", $outputJsonWithStr), $outputJsonWithStr)
```